# Android Black Roboto font style

Tags: android, fonts, roboto

I would like to apply Black Roboto on a specific TextView. I defined a style, but I don't know how to set Black Roboto ?

In styles.xml file, I have this style:

```
<style name="IntroTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">48sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

in my layout.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/IntroTitle"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="@string/intro_title_screen_1"/>
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: do you have a ttf file for the font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help.

The correct answer in my case for **Black Roboto** is:

```
    <style name="IntroTitle">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

For more informations, check on: *android-sdk/platforms/android-/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml*

Answer (score 1):

Add the fontFamily attribute to your TextView

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/title"
style="@style/IntroTitle"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:text="@string/intro_title_screen_1"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif" 
android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

`android:fontFamily="sans-serif"` gives regular Roboto while `android:textStyle="bold"` makes it bold/black.

If however,  you have a Roboto-Black font file inside your assets folder and would like to apply it to your TextView, you're going to have to do it through code. For example:

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf"); 
yourTextView.setTypeface(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
```

in order to use Roboto font in your `TextView`.

I think you meant bold by Black Roboto, so you'll need to add:

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```